# How to Handle Concurrency .NET CORE

Tags: concurrency, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can someone suggest "handling concurrent best practices" in enterprise level .NET CORE application(WEB). Front end has been implemented using JQuery.
I need suggestion in following points
   - Multiple Client requests hit in database same time
   - What are MS SQL level handlers

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As far as I know transactions are still in the works for .Net core, but it would be interesting to hear if anyone knows anything